# C programming parameter error

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 void load_menu(void)
 void Printing(void)

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
  load_menu();
  return 0;
 }

 void load_menu(void)
 {
    int choice;

    do
    {
    printf("Menu\n\n");
    printf("\t1.Printing \n");
    printf("\t2. Exit \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1: printing();
        break;
    case 2: printf("Exiting. \n");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(0);

    }


   } while (choice != 2);



}

 void printing(void)
 {
  printf(". \n");
  return;
 }
```

I am not quite done with this program, but if I compile it, I get:

```
Error   1   error C2085: 'Print' : not in formal parameter list 
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'    
Error   3   error C2085: 'main' : not in formal parameter list  
Error   4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'          
Warning 5   warning C4098: 'load_menu' : 'void' function returning a value  
Error   6   error C2084: function 'void load_menu(void)' already has a body 
Warning 7   warning C4013: 'printing' undefined; assuming extern returning int  
Error   8   error C2371: 'printing' : redefinition; different basic types
```

What do I do here? Excuse me. I started programming in C about few weeks ago.

Comment: you're missing semi-colons for one..

Comment: Try adding semicolons after your function declarations in lines 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need semi-colons at the end of your statements AND you need Printing to be **lower case**, to match your function declaration:

```
void load_menu(void);
void printing(void);
```

This builds and runs. Output is:

> Menu
>
> 1. Printing
> 2. Exit

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put semi-colons on the end of your function prototypes:

```
void load_menu(void);
void Printing(void);
```

After you fix this, you will also have an error because you declared `Printing` with a capital P, but define it and call is as `printing`.

Answer (score 0):

You need semi-colons at the end of your statements:

```
void load_menu(void);
void Printing(void);
```

Answer (score 0):

No semicolons after:

```
void load_menu(void)
void Printing(void)
```

Needed:

```
void load_menu(void);
void Printing(void);
```

Answer (score 0):

=> as many are saying you have missed the semi colons at the end of function prototype!

=> function `Printing` is called with the lower case 'p' in `switch - case 1` and `printing` is defined with lowercase 'p'. As C is case sensitive make sure that function names are called with the proper case.

=> and in function `printing` no need to have the `return`.